# How to make a C# winform program completely portable?

Tags: c#, winforms, portability

So, I wrote a program, and I would like to make it runnable on a school computer.
The problem is, I have no clue if there is the **.NET framework** installed, and we obviously have **no administrator rights** to install it.
Is there any way I could "include" the .NET framework with the program, so I don't have to worry about .NET framework not being installed?
The computers are all running **Windows 10**, if you're gonna ask for that.

By the way, the program is just a simple C# winform program, no additional dependencies such as SQL or something, no dlls or anything, just a normal C# program.

Comment: I believe Windows 10 should already come with Framework 4.6. Why not just target that?

Comment: It doesn't weigh that much.  Win10 already has the framework installed, you merely forgot to try it.

Comment: @HansPassant The comment on the answer by the OP says you are right :)

Comment: If you want a real portable application, that runs on any windows version, then you should use other compilers then from microsoft. I know this might sound weird, but this is how it is. One programming language I know that can do this is Delphi. No distributables needed of any kind, no runtime librarys, just copy the exe and run it. The size of the exe will be between 5 and 20 MB depending on how rich your UI is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The computers are all running Windows 10, if you're gonna ask for that.

Simply google for [does windows 10 have net framework](https://www.google.com/search?q=does+windows+10+have+net+framework)

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

> **Windows 10 (all editions)** includes the .NET Framework 4.6 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.
>
> **Windows 10 November 2015 Update (all editions)** includes the .NET Framework 4.6.1 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.
>
> **Windows 10 Anniversary Update (all editions)** includes the .NET Framework 4.6.2 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.
>
> **Windows 10 Creators Update (all editions)** includes the .NET Framework 4.7 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.
>
> **Windows 10 Fall 2017 Creators Update (all editions)** includes the .NET Framework 4.7.1 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.
>
> **Windows 10 April 2018 Update (all editions)** includes the .NET Framework 4.7.2 as an OS component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS component that is not installed by default.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel.

Comment: Oh, I should have checked. Thank you, next time I'll do my research ;)